# How do you move from a FragmentActivity to a Fragment?

Tags: android

I'm trying to sent an `OnClickListener` for a back button that needs to move from a `FragmentActivity` to a `Fragment`. I know you can move between Activities using an Intent such as:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(class1.this, class2.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

But how do you do it when `class1.this` is a `FragmentActivity` and `class2.class` is a `Fragment`?

Comment: Fragments are within fragment activity. You can do add(), replace() using the activity's getFragmentManager()

Comment: you should read more about fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Read and Find examples. [there](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html)

You can create you activity and attach fragment. that's it.